# Get Absolute URL From File Absolute PATH in PHP

Tags: php, url, uri, html-head

I have a function that checks existence of CSS/JS... file and then it returns whole `<script>` or `<link>` tag etc.
Before it returns, it checks existence of that file `file_exists()` by absolute path.
After that I'd like to get absolute URL of this file, to load even if request is like `domain.com/abc/def`. Is there any way to make it work everywhere (requests are all sent to index.php)?

I was inspired by Wordpress "enqueuing", but WP has URL saved in database, what I **don't want**.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: You know the root path for the website so you just cut that off the start and you have an absolute path for the URL.

Comment: If the files are located in the same filesystem, have you tried to translate the absolute path in to relative using the realpath function?

Comment: You can use `string_replase($basePath,$domen,$filePath)` where $basePath for example /var/www/project/ and $domen you bseUrl for example example.çom and etc.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: Root path is root of apache virtualhost, what to do if I had more domains on one like /domains/a.a /domains/b.b/ made just by HTACCESS rules

Answer (score 0):

With your help I came to solution;
I realized that all requests are redirected to index.php (if is not file) so I can use DOCUMENT_ROOT. I just needed fix \ from windows path, couse ussing WAMP. I've added protocol and URL was complete

```
/**
         * Returns absolute URL of given path
         * @param type $path
         * @return type
         */
        function absuri($path){
//for Windows servers (at the moment I use WAMP, i have Debian on my computer)
        $path = str_replace( '\\', '/', $path );
        return ( ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) ? 'https://' : 'http://'  ) . str_replace( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] , $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' , $path);
    }
```